# node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:936 throw err; ^ Error: Cannot find module 'side-channel'. When I run "npm start"

Tags: javascript, reactjs, npm, node-modules, side-channel-attacks

I encountered this error when I run `npm start`  to view my react app.

```
> react-scripts start

node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:936
  throw err;
  ^

Error: Cannot find module 'side-channel'
Require stack:
- C:\Users\USER-PC\Documents\Projects\frontend\Info_site\node_modules\qs\lib\stringify.js
- C:\Users\USER-PC\Documents\Projects\frontend\Info_site\node_modules\qs\lib\index.js
- C:\Users\USER-PC\Documents\Projects\frontend\Info_site\node_modules\webpack-dev-server\node_modules\express\lib\middleware\query.js
- C:\Users\USER-PC\Documents\Projects\frontend\Info_site\node_modules\webpack-dev-server\node_modules\express\lib\application.js
- C:\Users\USER-PC\Documents\Projects\frontend\Info_site\node_modules\webpack-dev-server\node_modules\express\lib\express.js
- C:\Users\USER-PC\Documents\Projects\frontend\Info_site\node_modules\webpack-dev-server\node_modules\express\index.js
- C:\Users\USER-PC\Documents\Projects\frontend\Info_site\node_modules\webpack-dev-server\lib\Server.js       
- C:\Users\USER-PC\Documents\Projects\frontend\Info_site\node_modules\react-scripts\scripts\start.js
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:933:15)
    at Function.Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:778:27)
    at Module.require (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1005:19)
    at require (node:internal/modules/cjs/helpers:102:18)
    at Object.<anonymous> (C:\Users\USER-PC\Documents\Projects\frontend\Info_site\node_modules\qs\lib\stringify.js:3:22)
    at Module._compile (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1103:14)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1155:10)
    at Module.load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:981:32)
    at Function.Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:822:12)
    at Module.require (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1005:19) {
  code: 'MODULE_NOT_FOUND',
  requireStack: [
    'C:\\Users\\USER-PC\\Documents\\Projects\\frontend\\Info_site\\node_modules\\qs\\lib\\stringify.js',     
    'C:\\Users\\USER-PC\\Documents\\Projects\\frontend\\Info_site\\node_modules\\qs\\lib\\index.js',
    'C:\\Users\\USER-PC\\Documents\\Projects\\frontend\\Info_site\\node_modules\\webpack-dev-server\\node_modules\\express\\lib\\middleware\\query.js',
    'C:\\Users\\USER-PC\\Documents\\Projects\\frontend\\Info_site\\node_modules\\webpack-dev-server\\node_modules\\express\\lib\\application.js',
ules\\express\\lib\\application.js',
    'C:\\Users\\USER-PC\\Documents\\Projects\\frontend\\Info_site\\node_modules\\webpack-dev-server\\node_modules\\express\\lib\\express.js',
    'C:\\Users\\USER-PC\\Documents\\Projects\\frontend\\Info_site\\node_modules\\webpack-dev-server\\node_modules\\express\\lib\\express.js',
    'C:\\Users\\USER-PC\\Documents\\Projects\\frontend\\Info_site\\node_modules\\webpack-dev-server\\node_modules\\express\\index.js',
    'C:\\Users\\USER-PC\\Documents\\Projects\\frontend\\Info_site\\node_modules\\webpack-dev-server\\lib\\Server.js',
    'C:\\Users\\USER-PC\\Documents\\Projects\\frontend\\Info_site\\node_modules\\react-scripts\\scripts\\start.js'
  ]
}
```

And then I tried to install the module with this command:

```
npm i side-channel
```

I still got an error:

```
npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\USER-PC\AppData\Local\npm-cache\_logs\2022-10-04T15_30_26_716Z-debug-0.log
```

What could possibly be the problem? I ran the start command just after installing the dependencies with 'npm install' command.

Answer (score 0):

You can try removing node_modules and reinstalling all modules with `npm install`

To show your modules as of npm 7 for windows:

```
Global modules: npm ls --link --global

Local modules: npm ls --link
```

To unistall package run

```
npm uninstall <module_name>
```

To install just run

```
npm install <module_name>
```

Comment: I just did, deleted the node modules and reinstalled it with ```npm install``` but I got this error: ```npm ERR! Invalid Version: ``` @GSriram

Answer (score 0):

It worked now. I had to delete the `yarn.lock` in my project, after deleting the `node_modules` file, then I ran the command again: `npm install`

Answer (score 0):

The best solution i have found for this problem is to uninstall and reinstall react.

**This will uninstall React**

to make sure it's there and show dependencies run

```
npm ls -g --depth=0
```

output:

```
F:\Dev\NodeJS\node22
+-- create-react-app@5.0.1
+-- express@4.14.0
```

to uninstall run

```
npm uninstall -g create-react-app
```

to install run

```
npm install -g create-react-app
```